# How to pass value to `define N

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I am using the `iverilog` simulator, and I want to pass value to `N` during compilation. Which command do I need to use, and can anyone help me with the usage of `` `define ``?

```
`define N

module Nbcd(A, B ,S);
 input [N*4-1:0] A,B;
 output[N*4-1:0] S;

genvar i;
  generate
   for(i=0; i<=N-1; i=i+1)
      bcd (.A(A[4*i+3:i*4]),
           .B(B[4*i+3:i*4]).
           .S(S[4*i+3:i*4])
          );
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module Nbcd();
  reg [N*4-1:0] A,B;
  wire [N*4-1:0] S;
  integer i;

  Nbcd U1 (.A(A),.B(B),.S(S));

  initial begin
    for (i=o; i<=N-1; i=i+1)
      begin
        A=i;
        b=i+1;        
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that most simulators allow the `-define` command line option.

```
irun test.sv -define N=0
```

It is slightly different for [iverilog](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Iverilog_Flags#-D.3Cmacro.3E) use `-Dkey=value` ie

```
-DN=0
```

### Usage

To use `` `define `` (tick defines) you need to place a tick before it, so you use `` `N `` when you want to use the command line supplied value, eg:

```
module Nbcd(A, B ,S);
 input [`N*4-1:0] A,B;
 output[`N*4-1:0] S;
```

I have a [working example on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/7XV), with iverilog version 0.9.7. The value is supplied via command line `-DN=10` and displays this value in the simulation using `` $display("N : %d", `N); ``.

### Tip

You may also want to add the code below, so that it can run without the command line option or remind users it is required:

```
`ifndef N
  `define N 0
`endif
```